# How do I create a nested list from a list of ages?

Tags: python

I am downloading tables of data in csv format from an online model.

The data includes a column for age.

My program works fine when all the data in the column has the one age, but now I am downloading data for a large range of ages so that I might have 400 rows of data at age 1 Billion Years, and then 350 at 1.1 Billion Years, etc.

There are around 30,000 rows and 40 columns in my csv file.

I thought I would create nested lists controlled by the age, and then loop through each sub-list.

I pick my data up as follows

```
log_age = data_upload[:,2]
mass = data_upload[:,5]
log_L = data_upload[:,6]
log_Teff = data_upload[:,7]
log_g = data_upload[:,8]
mbolmag = data_upload[:,24]
Umag = data_upload[:,25]
Bmag = data_upload[:,26]
```

How would I go about creating nested lists from these individual lists?

To generalise the problem if I have a list as follows:

age = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.2,1.2,1.2...]

how do I get it into the following format:

[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1],[1.2,1.2,1.2...]]

I would need to do this for all the lists using the structure of the age list.

I am thinking a list comprehension might be the way to go? I have come across them but don't really know how to use them.

There is a command called np.unique which will list the unique numbers in my original list so I can start by:

```
unique_age = np.unique(age)
nested_age = [[] for _ in range(len(unique_age))]
```

I could then repeat this for all the nested lists that I want to create, but then I have to go through each list and convert them to a nested list.

Could someone show me how to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to generate the result like this:

```
from collections import Counter
age = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.2,1.2,1.2]
c = Counter(age)
result = [[k]*v for k,v in c.items()]
print(result)
# Result would be: 
# [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1], [1.2, 1.2, 1.2]]
```

Line 3 means:

- Group the list according to the content of list,
- the item of Counter result looks like a dict, the key is age, while the value is frequency of each age.

Line 4 means:

1. Iterate the item of Counter result, get the keys(k) and values(v)
2. Create list of same value by [k]*v

Comment: Thanks Kason.  I really like that solution.  I am not a very experienced programmer.  I know of dictionaries but I never use them.

Comment: You are welcome, Naz. There is a long way to go, enjoy it ^_^